# There is some issue regarding to setting cookie in the node server and i want to access the browser cookie in the frontend like react.using npm module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

Unable to access the cookie (JWT token) that is set by the node server

```js
  .status(object.status)
  .cookie(
     "AdminJwt",
     token,
     {
         expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600 \* 1000),
         httpOnly: true,
         sameSite: "strict",
         path:'/'
     }
  )
  .send(object);
```

This is how I'm trying to set cookies on the server side and I want to access the cookie using the npm module like `react-cookie` or `js-cookie` in my reactjs-based frontend application. And the code is

```
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

const [cookies,setcookie] = useCookies(['jwttoken']);
console.log(cookies['jwttoken']);
console.log(useCookies(['jwttoken']));
```

using this code the cookie cant accessing and the result became undefined. Give me a solution for the problem?

give me the explanation for the problem and give me a good solution `your text`

Answer (score 0):

I use `import Cookies from 'js-cookie'` and `const darkModeCookie = Cookies.get('darkMode')` to get my cookie data

edit: httpOnly needs to be false when you set the cookie on server side.

Comment: bro i am also tried with the js-cookie NPM module and can't get the cookie. i think because of i am setting cookie in the server side.

Any body know the cookie setting code in the server with the httpOnly  and the path for the cookie data

Comment: oh, try flipping httpOnly to the opposite value. I think it needs to be false to pull cookies on the front end. I'll check one of my controllers to verify edit: yes, my controller has httpOnly to false. That allowed me to pull cookies on React side